# Log warning: Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=springHikariConnectionPool)

Tags: hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP 2.4.6 and at Tomcat 8 startup, I get a warning message:

```
01-Aug-2016 11:18:01.599 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
[2016-08-01 11:18:01,654] Artifact blueberry:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-08-01 11:18:01,655] Artifact blueberry:war exploded: Deploy took 33,985 milliseconds
Aug 01 2016 11:26:52.802 AM [DEV] (HikariPool.java:614)
WARN : com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - 9m13s102ms - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=springHikariConnectionPool).
```

I don't see any other errors or issues reading/writing from the DB.  Is this something to be concerned about?  I tried searching around, but no luck.

We're also using Hibernate 4.3.8.Final over MySQL 5 and the MySQL 5.1.39 connector with Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE. We're working to upgrade to Hibernate 5 and will see whether this goes away, but don't know whether that will matter.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There's a good [rundown](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/inAL5wyUIxk) of why clock leap detections might legitimately occur.  To quote the external link by Brett Woolridge:

> This runs on the housekeeper thread, which executes every 30 seconds.  If you are on Mac OS X, the clockSource is
>   System.currentTimeMillis(), any other platform the clockSource is
>   System.nanoTime().  Both in theory are monotonically increasing, but
>   various things can affect that such as NTP servers.  Most OSes are
>   designed to handle backward NTP time adjustments to preserve the
>   illusion of the forward flow of time.
>
> This code is saying, if time moves backwards (now < previous), or if
>   time has "jumped forward" more than two housekeeping periods (more
>   than 60 seconds), then something strange is likely going on.
>
> A couple of things might be going on:
>
> 1. You could be running in a virtual container (VMWare, AWS, etc.) that for some reason is doing a particularly poor job of maintaining
>      the illusion of the forward flow of time.
> 2. Because other things occur in the housekeeper thread -- specifically, closing idle connections -- it is possible that for some
>      reason closing connections is blocking the housekeeper thread for more
>      than two housekeeping periods (60 seconds).
> 3. The server is so busy, with all CPUs pegged, that thread starvation is occurring, which is preventing the housekeeper thread from running
>      for more than two housekeeping periods.
>
> Considering these, maybe you can provide additional context.
>
> EDIT: Note that this is based on HikariCP 2.4.1 code.  Make sure you
>   are running the most up-to-date version available.

(It also looks like the parameters were updated on the warning statement in the latest code.)

Comment: Reason 3 is also occuring when you are debugging your application and are waiting longer than two housekeeping periods (60 seconds) at one breakpoint. After continuing the progress, Hikari is complaining with warnings like in the question above.

Comment: That was my case using IntelliJ. Thank you.

Comment: Adding a new situation where it happened to me: I'm deploying multiple containers in docker. One of them contains the SpringBootApplication where it's is used Spring JPA with HikariCP. The problem occurs when Docker balances resources between containers, slowing down the execution of housekeeping periods in this specific container

Comment: Or, you are running on a laptop, and it went to sleep

Comment: @RigobertoPeña: and do you know how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 163):

One other reason if you run the app locally and the computer went to sleep it happens. In that case, you don't need to do anything configure wise.

Comment: While this is a perfect legitimate reason, along with others mentioned on this page, I wonder, why it's logged as a WARNING? If it were just an info, most likely this frequently searched SO page wouldn't even exist.

Comment: PR added: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/pull/2038

Comment: this was exactly my problem, I was running app locally on mac.

Comment: That happened to me too. 

I agree that it should be a WARN, because we always need to be aware of problems that may occur in a production environment. 

So, it's a warning about hibernation, either of the machine or our service thread.

Maybe can increasing some additional information, like "checks if the machine was suspended".

Answer (score 12):

Another reason why this is happening is due to **excessive garbage collection**, when **garbage collection** was running for a longer time within two executions of housekeeping thread, trying to free up some memory(e.g exactly when an application thread was running a 'select' query). Since the GC was blocking all application threads including the housekeeping thread, as such my suspicion is that the clock "leapt" due to that.

Comment: I'm facing exact same issue. Do you have any solution for the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025068/issue-post-running-select-query-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-e

Comment: Yep, same message before Out Of Memory occurred..

Answer (score 8):

I was facing this issue in a spring boot MySQL work in an AWS T2 micro 1GB RAM instance . After an hours effort and nothing moving forward , observed that CPU usage was going towards 100% . Then I made the instance T2 medium having 4 GB RAM and 2 vCPUs. After that I faced no problem

Answer (score 6):

I was facing this issue because of an infinite loop in my `hashCode` method of the Entity.

Two entities had `OneToMany` relationship and I was using lombok `@Data` annotation which generates `equals` and `hashcode` implementation itself by calling `hashCode()` method for each attribute which was causing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue when I ran my spring boot application with microservices on the Linux machine. After some investigation found out that, the server has only 8GB memory. Increasing Memory(RAM) to 16GB fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening at the start of your spring-boot application

```
org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
```

then run your application with the following Program Arguments

```
--spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap_mode=default
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue on AWS EC2.

It seems that AWS moved, or at least restarted, my EC2 instance because of what I believe to be very high CPU and memory usage. It seems that AWS believed the EC2 started to malfunction and therefore moved it or did something similar.

This caused the process to freeze for some time while the VM was moved from one machine to another, and I experienced this issue.

I might be wrong about the cause, but the error seemed to often and only happen when the resource usage was very high for a longer period of time.

Solution: Reduce or limit the CPU and/or Memory consumption or switch to better hardware.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution**:
I've noticed that the Kubernetes backend pods were using 100% resources. I've increased the CPU and the RAM (doubled) and the error was fixed.

**Cause**: Probably, because all the resources were used, the Garbage Collector tried to free more resources and thus the HikariPool was affected by the GC cleanup.

P.S.: Springboot 2.7 was used

Answer (score 0):

I stopped all services and restarted also solved the problem。

Comment: This is unlikely to resolve the issue permanently.  See my answer.