# AWS ec2 instance thread starvation or clock leap

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hikaricp

Recently i have running a java spring boot program on ec2 instance which is a ubuntu 16.04 server, i just upgrade java application to springboot 2.0 and implement some schedule job.

Usually i use nohup to keep the java program running, but recently everyday i will see the logs have some thread starvation or clock leap warning, and my java program just dead. May i know is this thread starvation kill the nohup program? how to fix the thread starvation problem.

By the way, because of the schedule job, i have changed ubuntu server timezone to some other timezone instead of the utc timezone. is this causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38703876/1695906

Comment: Hi thank you for you response, but i try this before, cause my spring boot version is 2.0, somehow it has the 2.7.8 hikaricp dependency, but this problem still exist, is it spring boot problem? or aws server problem?

Comment: Same problem here, can't find an answer :(