# HikariPool- Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta

Tags: hikaricp

Here hikari conf:

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://some_ip/myProject
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
username=username
password=pass
connectionTestQuery=SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
maximumPoolSize=3
connectionTimeout=20000
```

In my Kotlin project:

```
   lateinit var ds: HikariDataSource
   val dbConfig = HikariConfig("hikari.conf")
    ds = HikariDataSource(dbConfig)

     if (!insertQuery.isEmpty()) {
                    val connection = ds.connection
                    val insert = connection.prepareCall(insertQuery)
                    insert.execute()
                    insert.close()
                    connection.close()
                }
```

And it's work fine.
Nice.

But sometime I get **warning** message in log like this:

```
2019-04-27 18:55:23,852 17519559 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=5m30s164ms615Âµs200ns).
2019-04-27 18:55:23,853 17519560 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=3, active=0, idle=3, waiting=0)
2019-04-27 18:55:53,857 17549564 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=3, active=0, idle=3, waiting=0)
```

As result it stop insert new records to db.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703876/log-warning-thread-starvation-or-clock-leap-detected-housekeeper-delta-springh

Answer (score 4):

If you are running on a mac and see this issue it's nothing to worry about and your laptop has gone to sleep.

Comment: Yup, this is what happened in my case.